# Jquery height of div is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jQuery code

```
console.log("height: " + $("#board_view_player_info").outerHeight(true));
```

prints the height of the following div element as **0** for the following element

```
<div id="board_view_player_info">
    <b> hello world <br><br/>helloooo</b>
</div>
```

How to retrieve the height of the div element.

Comment: Thanks . That was very fast . Yes it was hidden and after display recalculating works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told, element is hidden, and so, hidden elements don't have height or width (they are 0). If you need dynamic calculations, show element first, only then get it's dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

It's working as expected, may be your div will be hidden. If it's hidden then just show and calculate the width and hide again.

```js
console.log("height: " + $("#board_view_player_info").outerHeight(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="board_view_player_info">
    <b> hello world <br><br/>helloooo</b>
</div>
```